# Unexpected width of view

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout

I have a UIImageView object which has constraints "equal width" and "equal height" to "superview" (ViewController's main view).

[image]

When I debugging, imageView's width and height isn't equal with ViewController's width and height. Am I missing something ?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The constraints are applied somewhere between after `viewDidAppear` and before `viewDidLayoutSubviews`. It is really frustrating as you don't have access to the correct size until the view is already visible to the user.

Answer (score 0):

what you can do to cover the hole view is to add to the imageView trailing, leading, top and bottom constraints = 0 and remove the height and width constrains.

hope it helps.